# stored procedure format with like

Tags: sql

I would like to know if there is a way to format the sql with a parameter passed to it to get the result.

```
dim fName as string = Tom

exec SP_GetPersonInfo + fName 

@FName VarChar(255)

SELECT Gender, Height, Weight, Age
FROM Person
WHERE FirstName LIKE ('fName %') <-- how would I format this?
```

Comment: The presentation layer should handle the formatting, not the stored procedure.

Comment: I'm trying to get away from inline sql and use SP. If I use inline sql, I can format it like so. FirstName LIKE ('" + fname + " %') "

Comment: What do you mean "in bold"?

Comment: already fixed question asked. thought I had something highlighted in bold to show what I was referring to but I didnt.

Comment: So you don't mean "format it in bold". You mean "concatenate the parameter with the query, like `(" + fname + ")"`, right? When you say "format in bold", it usually means to present it in a font that has the **bold** attribute.

Comment: Side note: if this is about **SQL Server**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above, you'd write the query this way to work with the parameter `@FName`:

```
SELECT Gender, Height, Weight, Age
FROM Person
WHERE FirstName LIKE @FName + '%';
```

<strike>Making the result bold is another matter entirely. And, like Tim said, this should be handled by the user interface. You shouldn't be trying to hack formatting code into SQL statements.</strike>

**EDIT**: After your clarification, I believe the statement above is the parameterized equivalent to your statement:

```
FirstName LIKE ('" + fname + " %') "
```

Comment: sorry, what I meant in bold was to bold what I was referring to but I've already corrected what I said.

Comment: what I had in the comment above ... FirstName LIKE ('" + fname + " %')" ... is inline sql. I dont want inline sql. I want to move it to SP to get the same result as what i have as inline sql.

Comment: Right, that's what the first query I wrote above does. It can be part of your stored procedure and uses the variable `@FName` passed in.

Comment: what if @FName is equal to "Grant", that's a permission in sql which will throw an error. how do you go beyond this?

Comment: It doesn't work the way that you're thinking it does. Try it.

Comment: so let's say i have this instead now ... exec SP_GetPersonInfo + "'" + fName + "'" ... what would be the parameterized equivalent to  FirstName LIKE ('fName %')

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard character that can be used with the LIKE operator is dynamically evaluated at run time rather than statically evaluated at statement compile time.  What this means is that '%' needs to be part of the literal or string you give to the operator and not a part of the statement itself.

For example, the following Java statement enters a string into an ArrayList. The ArrayList contains the Strings that are parameters for a JDBC PreparedStatement.  The parameters are of the form

- "NAME" + "%"

so that a client may be looked up by specifying the first few characters of his or her name.  Note: This form allows many query optimizers to still use an index.

```
m_qlist.add(s[i] + "%");
```